# Use lowercase month names in Pelican urls

Tags: python, string-formatting, pelican

I'm using the static site generator [Pelican](https://github.com/ametaireau/pelican/). I've configured the [`ARTICLE_URL`](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/stable/settings.html?highlight=article_url#url-settings) setting to include the year and month in the url.

For example with

```
ARTICLE_URL = 'posts/{date:%Y}/{date:%b}/{slug}/'
```

My post url will be something like

```
/posts/2015/Dec/my-new-post/
```

I would prefer the month to be lowecase, i.e.

```
/posts/2015/dec/my-new-post/
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: `.lower()` after the string

Comment: @depperm where would you suggest putting `lower()`? Lowercasing `ARTICLE_URL` wouldn't work, I want to lowercase the strings that Pelican generates using `ARTICLE_URL`.

Comment: Easy way? Not really. They come from date formatting directly and in turn from your locale. Your best bet is to write a plugin to lowercase and set them as `override_url`/`override_save_as`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem and solved it by making a small [Pelican plugin](https://heyman.info/2020/oct/25/lowercase-month-names-in-pelican-urls/) that adds the lower case month name as a content metadata variable.

Here is the plugin:

```py
from pelican import signals

def add_lowercase_month_to_metadata(content):
    if "date" in content.metadata:
        content.metadata["lowercase_month"] = content.metadata["date"].strftime("%B").lower()
        content.metadata["lowercase_month_short"] = content.metadata["date"].strftime("%b").lower()

def register():
    signals.content_object_init.connect(add_lowercase_month_to_metadata)
```

Once it's activated you can use the new lowercase month name variables (`lowercase_month` and `lowercase_month_short`) in the `ARTICLE_URL` and `ARTICLE_SAVE_AS`:

```py
ARTICLE_URL = '/{date:%Y}/{lowercase_month_short}/{date:%d}/{slug}'
ARTICLE_SAVE_AS = '{date:%Y}/{lowercase_month_short}/{date:%d}/{slug}/index.html'
```

Comment: 5 short years later, an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
ARTICLE_URL = 'posts/{date:%Y}/{date:%b | lower }/{slug}/'
```